# Why doesn't checkbox work in React Native?

Tags: react-native

```js
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';

export default class All extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isSelected: true,
    };
  }

  checkBoxChanged() {
    alert('changed');
    this.setState({isSelected : !this.state.isSelected})
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;

    return (
        <Content>
          <View>
            {items.map((item) => (
              <View>
                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                  <CheckBox
                    value={this.state.isSelected}
                    onValueChange={() => this.checkBoxChanged()}
                  />
              </View>
            ))}
          </View>
        </Content>
    );
  }
}
```

This doesn't work.I mean nothing happens.
When I check on, nothing changes and it doesn't reach to checkBoxChanged().

I got stuck in this problem.
I would appreciate it if you could help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onValueChange={() => checkBoxChanged()}`

```
  <CheckBox
      value={this.state.isSelected}
      onValueChange={() => checkBoxChanged()} 
    />
```

And in `checkBoxChanged` function you can set the state to change the value of `isSelected`

```
checkBoxChanged(){ 
this.setState({isSelected : !this.state.isSelected})
}
```

> Moreover the checkbox has been deprecated you have to install

```
 @react-native-community/checkbox
```

check [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/checkbox#__docusaurus) link to know more.

Hope this helps

Comment: I installed @react-native-community/checkbox and changed the code as you told me but nothing changed :(

Comment: That is probably because you haven't initialized the state. see The "value" of the checkbox. If true the checkbox will be turned on. Default value is false. so you have to change the isSelected (which you will initialize in the state). and checkBoxChanged function toggels isSelected whenever checkbox is checked

Comment: so right after you begin the class, initialize state like this
class YouClassName extends React.Component {
state = {
isSelected: false
}

//...rest of the code

Comment: I use checkbox in map, so it doesn't work? I'm going to edit my question. I would appreciate it if you could check it out again :)

Comment: Since you are using map function it will display checkbox for every element in `items` array and since every checkbox  have same value (isSelected) so when you check any of the checkbox it will reflect in all of them.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native';

isChecked = false
checkBoxChanged() {
    alert('changed');
}

getCheckedStatus(){
    this.isChecked != this.isChecked;
    return this.isChecked;
}

<CheckBox
    activeOpacity={1}
    textStyle={{ color: colors.colorGray, fontSize: dimen.fontSize.textAppearanceBody1_16 }}
    containerStyle={styles.checkBoxContainer}
    checkedColor={colors.profileTabSelectedColor}
    uncheckedColor={colors.profileTabSelectedColor}
    title={'Gender'}
    checked={this.getCheckedStatus()}
    onPress={() => { this.checkBoxChanged() }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to tell you don't use checkbox from react-native it is deprecated, still if you are using it please see the below code, there is no onChange Prop, use onValueChange instead of onChange, and maintain a state and pass value prop to checkbox component.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/checkbox#__docusaurus

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CheckBox, Text, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

export default App = () => {
  const [isSelected, setSelection] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
        <CheckBox
          value={isSelected}
          onValueChange={setSelection}
          style={styles.checkbox}
        />
        <Text style={styles.label}>Do you like React Native?</Text>
      </View>
      <Text>Is CheckBox selected: {isSelected ? "" : ""}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should be

```
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native';

checkBoxChanged() {
  alert('changed');
}

<CheckBox onValueChange={()=>this.checkBoxChanged()} />
```

You are calling the function directly instead of calling it on click.
This checkbox works only in Android so better use the one from react-native elements
https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox are being deprecated from react-native-element but it can be used from react native component.

to use them.
Install : npm install @react-native-community/checkbox --save

Usage:

```
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';
```

Inside you  use this element

```
<CheckBox  value={this.state.check}
                            onChange={()=>this.checkBoxText()} />
```

And inside your class

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        check: false
        };
```

Declare a function outside your constructor area.
create:

```
checkBoxText() {
        this.setState({
            check:!this.state.check
        })
       alert("Value Changed to " + this.state.check)
    }
```

It will create your clickable Check-box on your application.